# Set/Change TThread.FreeOnTerminate while on TThread.OnTerminate

Tags: delphi, tthread

I've been trying to to set the `FreeOnTerminate` property **in** the `OnTerminate` procedure but it seems like it's either too late to set it or it's completely ignoring the `write` procedure.

How can I set/change the `FreeOnTerminate` property **in** the `OnTerminate` procedure?
Are there any workarounds for that?

A little code:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure OnTestThreadTerminate (Sender : TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  TTestThread = class (TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
end;


var
  Form2: TForm2;
  GlobalThreadTest : TTestThread;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GlobalThreadTest                    := TTestThread.Create (True);
  GlobalThreadTest.OnTerminate        := Self.OnTestThreadTerminate;
  GlobalThreadTest.FreeOnTerminate    := True;
  GlobalThreadTest.Resume;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // 2nd Button to try to free the thread...
  // AFTER BUTTON1 has been clicked!
  try
    GlobalThreadTest.Free;
  except
    on e : exception do begin
      MessageBox(Self.Handle, pchar(e.Message), pchar(e.ClassName), 64);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.OnTestThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TTestThread(Sender).FreeOnTerminate := False;                        // Avoid freeing...
  ShowMessage (BoolToStr (TTestThread(Sender).FreeOnTerminate, True)); // FreeOnTerminate Value has been changed successfully!
end;

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
begin
  // No code needed for test purposes.
end;

end.
```

Comment: You have a data race.
Once you set FreeOnTerminate to True, and call Resume or
Start, then you are no longer able to refer to the thread
reliably. The design of FreeOnTerminate is that it is set to
True once and never subsequently modified. Whatever you
are trying to do, your solution is wrong.

Comment: Set FreeOnTerminate when you wish to absolve yourself of
resposnsibility to call Free on the thread object. When you
do so you must not hold a reference to the thread instance.
If you want some involvement in destruction of the thread
then do not set FreeOnTerminate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just don't understand why it wouldn't work. It's not a big deal to implement a little detail like that. It should be be easy to check `FreeOnTerminate` one last time after `OnTerminate` is finished... Thank you for your info.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Problem has been solved. I just don't understand why it wouldn't work in the first place.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What @David means: what condition desides on whether you finaly want to set `FreeOnTerminate` False? Because this sounds like [an XY-question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @MasonWheeler published a framework for executing an anonymous procedure through a postmessage call. [`Delayed Action, revisited`](http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/454/delayed-action-revisited). Call it in your `OnTerminate` handler by `DelayExec( procedure begin TTestThread(Sender).Free; end);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look to the sources of `ThreadProc` in Classes.pas, you will find that FreeOnTerminate is evaluated to a local variable `Freethread` before calling the OnTerminate event in DoTerminate.
After calling DoTerminate the thread is freed depending of the now outdated variable: `if FreeThread then Thread.Free;`.
You could start the thread without FreeOnTerminate and use  PostMessage with an own message e.g. WM_MyKillMessage (WM_APP + 1234) called in OnTerminate to free the thread after leaving the OnTerminate event.

This could look like:

```
const
  WM_KillThread = WM_APP + 1234;
type

  TTestThread = class (TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
    Destructor Destroy;override;
end;
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ............... 
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
    procedure WMKILLTHREAD(var Msg:TMessage);message WM_KillThread;
  end;


procedure TForm2.OnTestThread(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage ('OnTestThread');
  PostMessage(handle,WM_KillThread, WPARAM(Sender), 0);
end;

procedure TForm2.WMKILLTHREAD(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
   TTestThread(Msg.WParam).Free;
end;

destructor TTestThread.Destroy;
begin
  ShowMessage ('Destroy');
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: I really like the idea of posting a new message to the queue since `OnTerminate` is called in the context of the Mainthread. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

`FreeOnTerminate` is evaluated after `Execute()` exits but before `DoTerminate()` is called to trigger the `OnTerminate` event.  You can change `FreeOnTerminate` until `Execute()` exits, then it is too late.  So a workaround would be to trigger `OnTerminate` manually from inside of `Execute()`, eg:

```
type
  TTestThread = class (TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure DoTerminate; override;
  end;
```

```
procedure TTestThread.Execute;
begin
  try
    ...
  finally
    // trigger OnTerminate here...
    inherited DoTerminate;
  end;
end;

procedure TTestThread.DoTerminate;
begin
  // prevent TThread from triggering OnTerminate
  // again by not calling inherited here...
end;
```

The only gotcha is that if `Terminate()` is called before `Execute()` is called then `TThread` will skip `Execute()`, but it will still call the overridden `DoTerminate()`.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you want to set `FreeOnTerminate` False in some sort of condition, but let it otherwise stay True. If that condition by any chance depends on whether its termination is natural (Execute ended normally without intervention) or manual (Terminate is called), then I suggest you do the exact opposite: create the thread with `FreeOnTerminate = False` and set it True when the `Terminated` property is False:

```
procedure TTestThread.Execute;
begin
  ...
  if not Terminated then
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;
```

See its functioning for example in [When to free a Thread manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8252804/757830).