# Why does WaitForMultipleObjects fail with multiple thread handles?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2

In the following test program each test thread adds its handle to a global `TThreadList` when it starts executing, and removes its handle from the same list when its execution is about to end.

For testing purposes, additionally, each thread makes sure it adds its handle  before the main thread locks the list (to duplicate their handles and start waiting on them to finish). The threads also make sure they don't remove their handles before the main thread locks the list.

The test program runs fine for about up to 50-60 threads. After that, the `WaitForMultipleObjects` call start to fail with `WAIT_FAILED`, `GetLastError` returns 87 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`). Currently it starts 100 threads. My question is, what am I doing wrong?

The program is compiled with XE2 - update 4, 32-bit target platform. Test box is W7x64.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  windows,
  sysutils,
  classes,
  syncobjs;

type
  TTestThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FAckStarted: TEvent;
    function GetAckHandle: THandle;
    class var
      ThreadList: TThreadList;
      WaitEnd: THandle;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property AckHandle: THandle read GetAckHandle;
  end;

{.$DEFINE FREEONTERMINATE}

constructor TTestThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FAckStarted := TEvent.Create;
{$IFDEF FREEONTERMINATE}
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
{$ENDIF}
end;

destructor TTestThread.Destroy;
begin
  FAckStarted.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
begin
//  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('%d starting -------------', [Handle])));
  ThreadList.Add(Pointer(Handle));
  FAckStarted.SetEvent;

  NameThreadForDebugging(AnsiString(IntToStr(Handle)));

  WaitForSingleObject(WaitEnd, INFINITE);
  ThreadList.Remove(Pointer(Handle));
//  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('%d leaving -------------', [Handle])));
end;

function TTestThread.GetAckHandle: THandle;
begin
  Result := FAckStarted.Handle;
end;

const
  NumThreads = 100;

var
  DeferThreadEnd: TEvent;
  ThreadList: array of TThread;
  i: Integer;
  Thread: TTestThread;
  WaitThreadStart: THandle;
  LockList: TList;
  LockListCount: Integer;
  ThreadHandleArr: array of THandle;
  WaitRet: DWORD;
begin
  IsMultiThread := True;
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

  TTestThread.ThreadList := TThreadList.Create;
  DeferThreadEnd := TEvent.Create;
  TTestThread.WaitEnd := DeferThreadEnd.Handle;

  SetLength(ThreadList, NumThreads);
  for i := 0 to NumThreads - 1 do begin
    Thread := TTestThread.Create;
    ThreadList[i] := Thread;
    WaitThreadStart := Thread.GetAckHandle;
    Thread.Start;
    WaitForSingleObject(WaitThreadStart, INFINITE);
  end;

  LockList := TTestThread.ThreadList.LockList;
  LockListCount := LockList.Count;
  SetLength(ThreadHandleArr, LockListCount);
  for i := 0 to LockListCount - 1 do
{$IFDEF FREEONTERMINATE}
    Win32Check(DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess, THandle(LockList[i]),
            GetCurrentProcess, @ThreadHandleArr[i], SYNCHRONIZE, True, 0));
{$ELSE}
    ThreadHandleArr[i] := THandle(LockList[i]);
{$ENDIF}
  TTestThread.ThreadList.UnlockList;

  DeferThreadEnd.SetEvent;
  if LockListCount > 0 then begin
    Writeln('waiting for ', LockListCount, ' threads');
    WaitRet := WaitForMultipleObjects(LockListCount,
                              PWOHandleArray(ThreadHandleArr), True, INFINITE);
    case WaitRet of
      WAIT_OBJECT_0: Writeln('wait success');
      WAIT_FAILED: Writeln('wait fail:', SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    end;
  end;

  for i := 0 to Length(ThreadList) - 1 do begin
{$IFDEF FREEONTERMINATE}
    Win32Check(CloseHandle(ThreadHandleArr[i]));
{$ELSE}
    ThreadList[i].Free;
{$ENDIF}
  end;
  DeferThreadEnd.Free;
  TTestThread.ThreadList.Free;
  Writeln('program end');
  Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `WaitForMultipleObjects()` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) states:

> The maximum number of object handles is MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS.

The value of `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` is 64 (defined in `winnt.h`), so 100 handles is over the limit.  However, the documentation also explains how to overcome that limit:

> To wait on more than MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles, use one of the following methods:
>
> - Create a thread to wait on MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles, then wait on that thread plus the other handles. Use this technique to break the handles into groups of MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS.
> - Call RegisterWaitForSingleObject to wait on each handle. A wait thread from the thread pool waits on MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS registered objects and assigns a worker thread after the object is signaled or the time-out interval expires.

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136775/) for an example of the first technique.

Comment: There's also a possibility to use a variation of [this approach](http://tondrej.blogspot.com/2016/03/the-strange-limitation-of-64-threads.html): interlocked-incremented/decremented counter and a single event to wait for.

Comment: Thanks for editing.  I feel a bit bad taking credit for a better answer than mine :-)

Comment: Also note that the 64 object limit is actually a kernel side limit.  Redefining MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS or even reimplementing the userland side of WaitForMultipleObjects won't do much.  You just need to work around this particular limit.