# When does background threads prevent the process of being terminated?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy, terminate

Our program creates a background thread at the beginning of the program. The background thread does some database integrity checks and checks for stuff in the Internet using Indy. After 10 seconds, the background thread should be finished and since FreeOnTerminate is true, it will also clean itself up.

We have noticed that in some cases, if the user closes the program too quickly, the process will still be alive until the background thread is finished.

Since we couldn't exactly reproduce the issue, I have created a demo project to try a few things:

```
type
  TBackgroundThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

{ TForm1 }

var
  bt: TBackgroundThread;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  // Create a background thread which runs X seconds and then terminates itself.
  bt := TBackgroundThread.Create(false);
  bt.FreeOnTerminate := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // The user closes the app while the background thread is still active
  Sleep(2000);
  Close;
end;

{ TBackgroundThread }

procedure TBackgroundThread.Execute;
var
  i: integer;
  x: cardinal;
begin
  inherited;

  // Simulate some work that the background thread does
  x := MaxInt;
  for i := 0 to MaxInt do
  begin
    x := Random(x);
  end;
end;
```

The result is a bit surprising to me: After I close the MainForm, the process will be immediately terminated and the background thread will get hard-killed.

Now I have a few questions about this:

1. After the closing of the MainForm (= exit of the main thread), should I manually terminate all created threads via .Terminate or will that be done automatically?
2. Shall my threads only check for Self.Terminated or should they also check for Application.Terminated ?
3. Why does my busy thread as shown above gets immediately killed when I close the application? I expected that the process Project1.exe will run until all threads have finished by themselfes. (And as described above, we had seen an application where the main form is closed, but a thread is preventing the process of being closed).
4. How is it possible then, that our real application's process does not terminate because of a running background thread? Might it have something to do with the Internet stuff, which might cause the app to wait until a connection timeout is reached?

Comment: Hi. That's a lot of questions, but we all have been there. I recommend you to read Joe Duffy's  book "Concurrent Programming on Windows" to learn the basic concepts(not so basic though), then read the Delphi documentation.

Comment: I think Indy is blocking your thread to finish immediately. You can have blocking sockets with timeout I guess.

Comment: But @Lurd, does the blocking socket go so far as to prevent `ExitProcess` from killing the thread? I doubt it.

Comment: @RobKennedy well, there have been versions of Indy with horrible destructors which, if called, wait until all TidThread etc. instances have been terminated. For such reasons, I avoid plonking Indy components onto forms and datamodules and just create them in whatever thread needs to use them.  If the dodgy destructors never get called, they can't hold up the app close progression by preventing ExitProcess() from being reached.

Comment: In general - don't plonk threaded subsystem components onto forms.  If you do, freeing the owning form on app close will attempt to free the component which, if internally threaded, may get stuck waiting for threads to terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing the main form is not synonymous with exiting the main thread. Code continues to run after the form is closed. In particular, units are finalized.

If you handle your test thread's `OnTerminate` event, or put a breakpoint in the `Terminate` method, you'll see that it's not called automatically when your program exits. You'll have to call it yourself. But note also that a thread doesn't stop running just because `Terminate` is called. It continues running until it stops itself or it's terminated forcefully. Call `WaitFor` to wait for it to terminate.

Don't bother checking `Application.Terminated`; the thread's property should be sufficient.

Your thread gets terminated forcefully as your program exits because eventually your program calls `ExitProcess`, and one of the things the OS does there is to terminate all other threads. It doesn't call `Terminate` on them because the OS doesn't know about Delphi classes and methods.

You'll have to do some more debugging to determine why your program doesn't terminate promptly for your customers. You say you can't reproduce the problem in house, and you've written a test program that doesn't exhibit the problem, either. You'll have to find a customer who will cooperate with your further debugging efforts. Do you really *know* it's the thread that's holding things up, or is that just a guess so far?

Comment: It is not safe to call `Waitfor` on a thread with `FreeOnTerminate` set. See [A proper way of destroying a TThread object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1092831/576719).

Comment: Thank you. Now, many things became more clear. I refactored most of the code and do not use `FreeOnTerminate` anymore. Instead, I write all created threads into an ObjectList, and every element will be handled with `Terminate`+`WaitFor`+`Free` on the program termination (finalization of the unit). In each thread I am checking `Self.Terminated` regulary.